# How to install laravel 5.8 with xamp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

i am newbie with laravel and tryng to download 5.8 version in a server xamp.
But, when i try the command in the terminal of Xamp:
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.8.*"`
returns

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.8.* in a version installable using your PHP verson 8.0.5
```

Someone have a idea of what i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use Laravel 5.4, then you'd need to go with PHP 7.* and I'd recommend going with Wamp (https://www.wampserver.com/en/) instead of Xampp, which allows you to switch between php versions with one click.

However try using laravel 8 if laravel 5.4 is not a requirement

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.8 doesn't support php 8, you should probably consider using laravel 8

Comment: Well, its the best choice.
But, the haystak want to create the project in laravel 5.8. How can i install php7.1.3 or greater in xamp?

Answer (score 2):

`Xampp` versions follows PHP's, so you should download something like 7.1.3x. This can be done on the download page, assuming you are using windows this is the [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/).

In general for choosing `PHP` versions, it is most optimal to go with the version that is used on the production server.